# Interview question: Number of bit swaps required to convert one integer to another

Tags: bit-manipulation

A friend of mine was asked this question in an interview. I wasn't able to figure out a solution to this.
Question -

Write a function to calculate the number of bit swaps required to convert one integer to other.

Comment: Was there a particular language?

Comment: Is it known that both integers have the same number of 0 bits and the same number of 1 bits?

Comment: @Omnifarious - No this information is not known

Comment: It is not clear what you have to do: toggle bits (`XOR`) or swap pairs of bits in the number (precond: `num_1bit(N1) == num_1bit(N2)`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bit operation which can be used to figure out which bits are different is xor.  Each `1` in the xor value will tell the different bit between the two integers.

```
int getBitSwapCount(int x, int y) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int z = x^y; z!=0; z = z>> 1) {
        count += z & 1;
    }
    return count; 
}
```

Comment: Not correct.  :-)  They don't want the number of differing bits, but the number of swaps.

Comment: The number of different bits is the same as number of swaps required

Comment: @Omnifarious && @user45* : yes, the number if different bits should be the same as number of swaps needed

Comment: A small problem corner case with this solution: If *(1)* you're dealing with signed integers, and *(2)* `x^y` happens to be negative, and *(3)* the `>>` operator in your preferred language performs an arithmetic shift in such a situation, *then* you'll end up in an infinite loop because `z` will never become zero.

Comment: No, it's half the number of bits that are different.  1100 ^ 1010 = 0110 = 2 bits = 1 swap (the middle 0 and 1)

Comment: @ Omnifarious - if you consider 'swap' as swapping 2 bits in the input integer, there is no solution when the input and output differ in the number of 1s and 0s, right?

Answer (score 3):

Interview questions aren't only about solutions, they're also (and this is generally even more important that finding a solution) giving you the opportunity to show how you would tackle a novel problem such as this.  How would you start on this ?  Is there any further information you'd like to know to help you solve it ?  Are there any standard functions (in any commonly-used programming language) you'd like to use ?

Give us your best shot, we'll play the interviewer(s) and prompt as you go ...

Answer (score 2):

XOR the values and then count the number of ones in the result

Comment: Why zeros? if x1 = 0 and x2 = 0 then x1 xor x2 = 0, i.e. all positions are zeros, but no swaps are needed. May be count ones?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see anything special about this question. Iterating over the bits of both integers, combining the current bits via XOR and incrementing a counter if the result is not equal to zero will give you the number of bits that differ in both values.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach

find and the binary string and calculate [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) by dynamic programming

Answer (score 0):

Take the XOR of 2 numbers (say a & b), and count the number of ones in the a^b

```
int bitsSwapRequired (int a, int b){
    int count = 0;
    for (int c = a ^ b; c!=0 ; c >> 1)
        count += c & 1;
    return count;
}
```

We can make it a bit better, rather than simply shifting c repeatedly while checking the least significant bit, we can continuously flip the rightmost bit set to 1 and count how long it takes c to reach 0. The operation c = c & (c-1) will clear the rightmost bit set to 1 in c.

```
int bitsSwapRequired (int a, int b){
    int count = 0;
    for (int c = a ^ b; c != 0; c = c & (c-1))
        count ++;
    return count;
}
```